# ZonedDateTime is returning same String for two different Timezone

Tags: datetime, java-8, java-time, zoneddatetime

I am trying to format current timestamp into two different time zone, But ZonedDateTime format is returning same output.

```
    DateTimeFormatter outputFormat = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendPattern("ddMMMyyyy HH:mm:ss").toFormatter();
    System.out.println(ZonedDateTime.of(LocalDateTime.now(), ZoneId.of("America/Phoenix")).format(outputFormat));
    System.out.println(ZonedDateTime.of(LocalDateTime.now(), ZoneId.of("Asia/Calcutta")).format(outputFormat));
```

above code snipped is returning same time stamp as

```
16Apr2022 13:28:19
16Apr2022 13:28:19
```

Can some one help me understand but its returning same String. What is correct way to format time in different time zone, using Java 8 Date Time APIs.

Comment: Those aren't timestamps - they're just local date/time values. You've basically said "Here's a local date and time - create a `ZonedDateTime` for it in two different time zones, then format just the local part of the result... so yes, you'll end up with the same result. What are you *trying* to achieve?

Comment: Using ZonedDateTime I want to print current timestamp at different zones

Comment: You should get the current timestamp from `Instant.now()`, not `LocalDatetime.now()`.

Comment: Use `ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("America/Phoenix"))` to get the correct time in your desired time zone. Then the two will also be different.

Comment: And even better, after you have called `now()` once, use the `withZoneSameInstant` method to convert to a different time zone.